# How to check few keywords in a string and assert if not present in Ansible tasks

Tags: ansible

I have a string like this

```
"3000 Native                           active    Po121, Po123"
```

I need to check if 3000 is present and active is present in this string. If not assert

I wanted to use `when` command  and `set_fact`. Check if the variable present and assert. (which I haven't finished). Right now I am just printing a message. This is not the good to way to do it. If I can assert directly when 3000 and active not present, that would be great.
Also another question about when, if it matches first condition, it prints the debug message. It should match both right as its an and?

```
var:
  vlan_output: "3000 Native                           active    Po121, Po123"

item={vlan_id: 3000, state: present}
```

I tried like this

```
 - name: Validate vlan for delete

   debug: msg="VLAN FAILED "

   when: item.state == "present" and "item.vlan_id not in vlan_output"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can directly use the when condition if "3000" and "active" is present in the output

I believe the vlan_id would be a registered variable so the value can be accessed using vlan_id.stdout.

The below play works with when and assert module of ansible

**for assertion +ve:**

command -->

```
ansible-playbook tmp.yml --extra-vars "vlan_output='3000 active'"
```

playbook -->

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Strings Matched"
      when: vlan_output | search("3000") and vlan_output | search("active")
    - debug:
        var: vlan_output
    - assert:
        that:
          - "'3000' in vlan_output"
          - "'active' in vlan_output"
```

output -->

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Strings Matched"
}

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "vlan_output": "3000 active"
}

TASK [assert] ****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

**for assertion -ve:**

command -->

```
ansible-playbook tmp.yml --extra-vars "vlan_output='is'"
```

playbook -->

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Strings Matched"
      when: vlan_output is not search("3000") and vlan_output is not search("active")
    - debug:
        var: vlan_output
    - assert:
        that:
          - "'3000' not in vlan_output"
          - "'active' not in vlan_output"
```

output -->

```
PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Strings Matched"
}

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "vlan_output": "is"
}

TASK [assert] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: First of all thanks to stack overflow we can get help from lot of sharp folks in the industry. Worked perfectly fine. I did try assert, I was not using " properly, so didn't work. Your solution worked perfectly fine. Thanks so much.

Comment: Happy that I could be of some help. Not sure if we can accept multiple answer on SO! If we can then please accept the answer and up vote the comment or else just up vote it

Comment: Also for another show command I get no output. vlan_output="" .  I need to check 3000 and active not in the output. This fails.  how do I fix it.  - assert:
    that:
      - not "item.vlan_id in vlan_output['stdout_lines'][0][0]"
      - not "'active' in vlan_output['stdout_lines'][0][0]"
  when: item.state == "absent"

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of issues here

Firstly, you should not quote `"item.vlan_id not in vlan_output"` - this is a string and will always evaluate to `True`.

Secondly, the `not in` test requires the operands to be type string (currently `vlan_id` is an integer).

You should see the behaviour you are looking for with these changes:

```
  vars:
    vlan_output: "3000 Native active Po121, Po123"
    item:
      vlan_id: "3000"
      state: present

  tasks:
    - debug: msg="VLAN FAILED"
      when: item.state == "present" and item.vlan_id not in vlan_output
```

Comment: Yes debug message worked fine. can you please explain little more about:  How to use integers when we use " ", also when to use {{ }} to get value of a variable or when to use value like item.vlan_id directly.